# Showcase of nice looking headers

Tags: header-footer

So I was searching through tex.stackexchange about headers, and I haven't seen this kind of topic.

I was thinking of including header in my thesis but I'm still not sure whether to do it or not.

Still regardless of my own issues, I was wondering do you guys, here on tex.stackexchange, have any preferred style or custom code to make your headers look nice and shiny :D

So if you have, why not boast a bit, and in turn help someone out who might need it in the future :)

Comment: Have a look to question [showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/74615#74615) including nice header and footers ...

Comment: I know of that topic, I was thinking of just headers, but this is also great :)

Answer (score 2):

For mine I wanted to have the section name on even pages and the chapter name on odd pages. I am a huge fan of small caps; therefore I wanted it in small caps. Here is what I had

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\small\textsc{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\small\textsc{\thesection.\ #1}}{}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
```

Comment: although this is the reverse of the traditional order, the approach is classic.  one comment on small caps, however.  small caps are classic, and if a title is all text, wonderful!  but if an author sticks in even a small bit of math, the result really looks abysmal, hence the (otherwise deplorable) practice of using all caps (except for the math) in a smaller size for headers.  (which is why `\uppercasenonmath` and `\MakeTextUppercase` were concocted.)